# Identifying a chip from its logo and chip markings - no obvious search engine results

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, markings

I've been unable to identify the MCU on a cheap consumer device board I'm examining, which is quite embarrassing as it's well marked and even has a logo. I can't match the logo to anything from memory, and various lists of logos don't have anything obvious. Googling/Binging the markings haven't yielded anything.

The chip markings are:

- MFC-G01
- CK7CKW
- JJ2047
- GD

[image: MFC-G01 CK7CKW JJ2057 GD ARM]

The USB port on the board is either for charging only, or the chip isn't enabling data, so no joy there.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: well, the ARM mark indicates that it's probably an ARM-based processor, but that doesn't really narrow it down much.

Comment: Yes, I was pleased when I saw the ARM logo as it means I can probably attach an SWD to it once I've got the pinout.

Searching 'GD ARM' got me to GigaDevices, but that doesn't seem to fit the rest of the markings/logo.

Comment: GD makes clones of STM32.

Comment: @Marko Buršič I'd expect some GD32Fxxx type markings if that were the case, such as [this example](https://cdn.hackaday.io/images/2751251565102862909.jpg) from a [hackaday article](https://hackaday.io/project/166974-stms-faster-compatible-by-gigadevice).

Comment: Maybe it is not a Gigadevice, the logo doesn't match.

Comment: I've not got the answer yet, but I have got a new lead. It seems like it **is** a GigaDevices chip or derivative of some kind. I found an image that matches the `GD ARM` labelling, as well as the `JJxxxx` label. My source is a [Product Change Notification](https://www.mouser.com/PCN/GigaDevice_PCN_00160_Logo_Rev1.1[1].pdf) that covers GD's change of logo in 2020. The logo in question is still different, but the some of the chip labels are close matches, so maybe I can get a bit closer to the product family with this.

If I do figure it out, I'll answer my own question.

Comment: I have found a device with a similarly labelled chip (`GD ARM`) on it that carries the identifier `GD32FFPRTGU6` which is a known GigaDevices product. I have some new probes arriving soon that should allow me to finally verify the model number of the originally-posted chip and close this question, as my cack-handed soldering killed my original one why trying to re-attach some debug leads. I have a couple more identical products but I'm not prepared to risk killing them the same way, so I'll be patient.